# using np.r_ function on preexisting list

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d list I'd like to merge row-wise, but I don't know how to do so because *np.r_* is not a function.

```
import numpy as np
xx_ravel = ['1,2,0']
xx_ravel = xx_ravel.extend([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
Z = np.r_[xx_ravel]
```

The behavior I'd like is the same as this code block:

```
import numpy as np
Z = np.r_['1,2,0',[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Where *Z* resolves to

```
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

I'm using *np.r_* on a list of *xx_ravel*, but what I want is to use it on just *xx_ravel*. How can I do such a thing?

Comment: Can you please include **all** necessary code and data to run your program? See: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderCécile, I've edited my post.